# moving a placemark in google earth using C#

Tags: c#, google-earth

I have been using Winform GEPlugin control example for my work.

http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/ExampleForm

my problem is i want to move my placemark (in C#, not KML), i tried a lot but it is not working.
kindly suggest me some solution for this. a sample of code will also be helpful.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post your code. And explain what you mean by "it is not working". Is it giving an error message? Throwing an exception? How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can move it through java script and in winform-GE Plugin there are functions like injectJavascript and invokeJavascript, we can make use of those functions to execute javascript function..

Even I'm not able to move it exactly but I'm able to create a new placemark and delete the previous one which will give a sense that placemarks are moving.

```
<script
src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAuPsJpk3MBtDpJ4G8cqBnjRRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQCzVBXTx2DYyXGsTOxpWhvIG7Djw"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addSampleButton(caption, clickHandler) {
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = caption;

    if (btn.attachEvent)
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', clickHandler);
    else
        btn.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

    // add the button to the Sample UI
    document.getElementById('sample-ui').appendChild(btn);
}

function addSampleUIHtml(html) {
    document.getElementById('sample-ui').innerHTML += html;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ge;
var placemark;

var counter = 0;

google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
    google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);

    addSampleButton('Create a Placemark!', buttonClick);
    addSampleButton('Remove last Placemark!', RemovebuttonClick);

}

function initCallback(instance) {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

    // add a navigation control
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

    // add some layers
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, true);

    // Get the current view.
    var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    lookAt.setRange(1000);
    // Set new latitude and longitude values.
    lookAt.setLatitude(11.50);
    lookAt.setLongitude(79.50);

    // Update the view in Google Earth.
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);

    createPlacemark();

    document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML = ge
            .getPluginVersion().toString();
}

function failureCallback(errorCode) {
}

function removePlacemark() {
    //counter--;
    // alert("placemark" + (counter -1));
    ge.getFeatures().removeChild(placemark);
}

function createPlacemark() {
    if (counter != 0)
        removePlacemark();
    placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
    placemark.setName("placemark" + counter);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

    // Create style map for placemark
    var icon = ge.createIcon('');
    icon
            .setHref('http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Transport/Transport%201/Car.png');
    var style = ge.createStyle('');
    style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
    placemark.setStyleSelector(style);

    // Create point
    var la = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    var point = ge.createPoint('');
    point.setLatitude(la.getLatitude());
    point.setLongitude(la.getLongitude());
    placemark.setGeometry(point);

    placemark.
    counter++;
}

function buttonClick() {
    createPlacemark();
}

function RemovebuttonClick() {
    removePlacemark();
}
</script>
```

You can try these script and if u r able to move by giving latitude and longitude, then please let me know